# How to get session variable value in payment page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, magento-2.1.7

How to get session variable value from `shipping` page to `payment` page ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you want to get from session variable?

Comment: If we select length value in shipping page its length must be displayed under shipping method in payment page as i uploaded both image Rohan Hapani

Comment: can you please update code which you have use for set the value

Comment: protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    ........
)
{
    ........        
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    ........
}


public function getCheckoutSession() 
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
} this i used but its not working for me  Rakesh Varma

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this below code will be useful for you or not. But, you can use the below code in your custom module to set, unset session

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    ........
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    ........
)
{
    ........        
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    ........
}


public function getCheckoutSession() 
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
}
```

By using **getCheckoutSession()** you can get value from session.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the above code Rohan Hapani

Comment: You can use this below code in your controller, block, helper etc. $this->_checkoutSession will be return object of checkoutSession data which is store in checkout page session

Comment: No its not working for me Rohan Hapani

Comment: It's whole object of checkout session. You need to get like this : $this->getCheckoutSession()->getCustomFunction(); //write your function which you want to get value from checkout session

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
) {

    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

public function getCheckoutSession() 
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession;
}
```

Where you want set your value

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->setShippingValue('someValueHere');
```

Where you want to get that value

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->getShippingValue(); //someValueHere
```

Then you unset the value:

```
$this->getCheckoutSession()->unsShippingValue();
```